# mysqldump blocking Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mysql

This is a trickier problem than it sounds.  I run Ruby/MySQL on many servers and use mysqldump w/o any problems.  However, I'm using an Ubuntu setup and it appears to be acting quite different than Fedora and RHEL.  When I backup the production server using mysqldump it causes Rails to become inaccessible.  Apache is still able to serve up images and CPU/memory usage is low, so it appears to be purely a contention with RoR and MySQL.  I am using InnoDB, which has allowed mysqldump to backup this exact same database on a Fedora server w/o any downtime.  However, the other server was running Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.

Here are the complete server specs:

```
Ubuntu 10
Rails 3
RVM
Ruby 1.9.2
Passenger
Apache
MySQL
```

Additional "clues":

- I can connect fine to the production database and access records using mysql client
- I can use Rails console to load the production environment and query tables using ActiveRecord
- I cannot access the production webserver through Apache/Passenger, nor can I access it when I run a production instance with Webrick (through 'rails s -e production')

Any thoughts as to why mysqldump would be blocking Rails (and only Rails)?

Comment: please use mysqldump with params --single-transaction

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this thing has an answer (from comments above):

> please use mysqldump with params --single-transaction – Neo Apr 22 at
>   14:59